# C- what exactly is SIGUSR1 syntactically

Tags: c, signals, kill

When I use SIGUSR1 in the kill() or signal() functions, what is it doing? Is it a macro? I read that it was user defined, but where is it defined? Can I make a SIGUSR10 (or programatically make an "array" of different signal types)?

Comment: It is probably defined in `<signal.h>` or a file included from that. You can't portably make up your own ones.

Comment: `SIGUSR1` is 'user defined' because the implementation never generates `SIGUSR1` itself (whereas signals such as `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGPIPE`, `SIGTERM` are generated by the system on occasion).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

User defined signals means that these signals have no definite meaning unlike `SIGSEGV`, `SIGCONT`, `SIGSTOP`, etc. The kernel will never send SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 to a process, so the meaning of the signal can be set by you as per the needs of your application. All these uppercase `SIG` constants are actually macros which will expand to an integer indicating a signal number in the particular implementation. Although user defined signals do not necessarily *need* to be defined, the signal numbers are already fixed in a particular implementation, and they can be safely re-purposed since they will not be sent by anything except for the user.

Traditionally, there have been two user-defined signals: `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`. However, recent implementations have something called "POSIX realtime signals" which offer several more user-defined signals.

Answer (score 6):

SIGUSR is, as the name implies, a signal reserved for use by the user (developer), without any "special" pre-defined meaning.  You can't make 10 of them, on most POSIX systems there are exactly two - SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2.

The symbol itself may or may not be a macro expansion, but will end up being a numeric value assignment-compatible with int.

To use it in a meaningful way, you will need to write a signal handler.  See the signal() manpage for details on how to do this.

Comment: Actually, [POSIX defines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html#tag_13_43): _The <signal.h> header shall define the following macros that are used to refer to the signals that occur in the system. Signals defined here begin with the letters `SIG` followed by an uppercase letter. The macros shall expand to positive integer constant expressions with type `int` and distinct values._  So the signal names should be macros.

Comment: POSIX 7 made a lot of things way nicer / saner, including this.   But you will find older systems that are not compliant.    Prior to 2005, the language that governed this was: *"The <signal.h> header shall define the following symbolic constants, each of which expands to a distinct constant expression of the type...*"    Much better now!  It's a likely safe bet that whatever system you are on here in 2022 is POSIX 7 compliant.  But you should not rely absolutely on it in general.   This is a minutia that OP was probably not very interested in, however.