# Git Fast Import - Sending the SIGUSR1 command

Tags: java, git, process, java-8, git-fast-import

I am writing a Java program that feeds data into the `git fast-import` function. Currently, I know all my formatting works and conforms to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import#_signals However, my problem is sending the final "kill" command: `SIGUSR1`.

I get things to work right now by running this command `type fast-import.script | git fast-import`. That fact that this works tells me my formatting and such is proper. But, I know there is a way to continuously run `git fast-import` and feed commands into its standard-input, but the very last command has to be `SIGUSR1`

Without sending a `SIGUSR1` the fast-import utility doesn't know to end. I have tried a few things:

1- Destroying the process using regular Java Process API commands such as

`fastImportProcess.destroyForcibly();`

2- Use a Java library [WinProcess](https://github.com/kohsuke/winp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jvnet/winp/WinProcess.java) ([Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.winp/winp)) to find the pid and kill it.

```
WinProcess wp = new WinProcess(fastImportProcess);
wp.killRecursively();
```

That didn't work either. And I tried combinations of things related to the Java Process API and the WinProcess API, etc. Although I can get WinProcess to force the fast-import utility to shut down, it doesn't actually create my commits.

3- Lastly, endlessly research what `SIGUSR1` is and all I can come up with is `SIGUSR` is some kind of user-defined signal. [C- what exactly is SIGUSR1 syntactically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736623/c-what-exactly-is-sigusr1-syntactically) Not too helpful.

I don't think this issue is Java related per-se, its really about how to use `git fast-import`. I notice when I run fast-import in the CLI, when I press `ctrl-c` the commits execute. But I don't know exactly how to do this in Java.

Comment: I have no idea about Java, nor about Windows. On Unix-like systems, one uses `kill` to send signals (signals originally were mostly fatal to programs, hence the name; this is no longer true, but the name remains). In Python, including on Windows, there should be an `os.kill` in the `os` module. See https://bugs.python.org/issue23948

Comment: @torek - I was hoping the Java Process API's `destroy` functions would do that, but it doesn't. Next, that `WinProcess` api seemed promising but it didn't work either.  Perhaps I am using them incorrectly?

Comment: I don't "do" Windows so I don't know the answer, but I'd probably start with the Python `os.kill` code to see how to use the Windows POSIX subsystem (if that's what it uses) to send POSIX-style signals. If your Windows version is old enough that it lacks a POSIX subsystem, I don't know what to look for next.